# Django migration: making a row not primary key, getting "ProgrammingError: multiple default values"?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am working with Postgres on a Django app and I want to make a model change, resetting a row so it is no longer the primary key.

This is what my model currently looks like in Django:

```
class Meeting(TimeStampedModel):
    row = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    total_items = models.IntegerField()
```

I have run `django-admin.py flush` to remove all data from the database. If I run `python manage.py makemigrations` I see `No changes detected`. So we are starting from a clean base.

Now I edit `row` in models.py so it is no longer the primary key:

```
row = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And run `python manage.py makemigrations` and set `1` as the default when asked:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to meeting without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> 1
Migrations for 'frontend':
  0007_auto_20150305_1129.py:
    - Add field id to meeting
    - Alter field row on meeting
```

That seems to run OK. Then if I run `python manage.py migrate`:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: debug_toolbar
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, frontend, sites, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying frontend.0007_auto_20150305_1129...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/meetings/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  ...
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/meetings/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "frontend_meeting"
```

Why is it telling me I have `multiple default values`?

Do I need to set a unique primary key value as a default - and if so, how can I do this?

This is what the migrations file looks like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('frontend', '0006_auto_20150305_1050'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='meeting',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, default=1, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='meeting',
            name='row',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=20),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: I had to simply delete my pre-existing migrations.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use an intermediate migration to achieve this:

1) Add `id = models.IntegerField()` to your model. 
Run **makemigrations** and then **migrate**.

2) Remove primary_key=True from the 'row'-field, and also remove the 'id'-field. Again run **makemigrations** and **migrate**.

Comment: This generally works, thanks, but: 1) It seems tidier to fit these into one migration manually; 2) If you have data in your table you need to fill the newly created `id` column with unique values and advance the auto sequence accordingly before step 2; 3) If any other tables have foreign key constraints pointing to that key, you need to remove them before step 2 and manually add new ones after step 2