# Django: migrate with id field

Tags: python, django

Using django 1.8

i removed `primary_key=True` arg from one of my model field, after makemigrations below migration file create with id field.

sample code from migration file :

```
migrations.AddField(
            model_name='transaction',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, default=1, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
```

when `python manage.py migrate`

Error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "app_transaction"`

And i don't have any data in that table.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876973/django-migration-making-a-row-not-primary-key-getting-programmingerror-multi

Comment: thanks @AjayGupta problem solved.